# Delete a single site's cookies in Chrome 59+?

Tags: google-chrome

The Chrome Settings page has been redesigned in Chrome version 59. Previously it was possible to remove a specific site's cookies (rather than obliterating every cookie created within the past hour) and even delete specific cookies.

Is there still a way to do this, without using extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 2:

If the cookies are for the site you're currently browsing, the easiest way to delete them is to open Developer Tools, go to the Application tab, and under Storage you'll find Cookies, with a cookie hierarchy for this site. You can add + delete individual cookies on this page, as well as right click the site in the left pane and select Clear to delete all of a site's cookies.

### Update:

As of Chrome ~ v61.0.3163.100, the flag mentioned below is no longer available, but enhanced cookie control *is* available in the Material Design Settings.

```
chrome://settings/content/cookies?search=cookie
```

---

### Old Answer

Chrome has an experimental feature which disables the new Material Design Settings page and reverts to the old Settings page style. From there, you can access the cookies the old way: Settings > Show advanced settings… > Content Settings... > All cookies and site data...

You can find the setting by entering this in your address bar:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-md-settings
```

If you're not familiar with Chrome's Experimental Features, read the warning at the top of the page before changing anything.